# Access the iOS device photos, music and videos using Windows Command prompt

Tags: ios, iphone, windows

I need to use the iOS device photos, musics, videos and files via  Windows Command prompt. Need to mount device and access files, import files, export files and delete files in my windows machine. I am explored on libimobiledevice library (http://quamotion.mobi/iMobileDevice/Article/howto-mount-apple-developer-disk) for mounting the iOS device but its not working for me its says mount status completed but drive is not available in my windows file explorer. I have installed itunes and libimobiledevice apps in my windows machine please help any thing i missed.

I am using the following command for mount ios device.

ideviceimagemounter.exe -t Developer DeveloperDiskImage.dmg DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature

Comment: The next link (http://quamotion.mobi/iMobileDevice/Article/howto-launch-app) says "The Developer Disk Image is mounted on your iOS device. For more information, see Mount the Apple Developer Disk" which would mean the image isn't mounted on your PC but on the iOS device. Do the commands you want not work?

Comment: ok thanks Sirens, If any way mount the device in windows machine and modifying files.